# MongoDB hangs randomly

Tags: ruby, mongodb

#### Overview

I have a ruby application that uses MongoDB as a database. While running tests for this application I am creating collections and indexes for every test case using `Minitest`.

The test environment is created using docker compose where one container is running the tests and the other container is running MongoDB.

#### Problem

When running the tests for the first time, after a while MongoDB gets stuck. Any request to query the collections doesn't respond.

I was able to connect to it before the tests started running using the command line client. When I checked the state of the server using `db.serverStatus()` I see that some operations have acquired locks. Looking at the `globalLock` field I understand that 1 operation has `write` lock and there are 2 operations are waiting to acquire `read` lock.

I am unable to understand why would these operations hang and not yield the locks. I have no idea how to debug this problem further.

MongoDB Version: 3.6.13
Ruby Driver version: 2.8.0

I've also tried other versions 3.6.x and 4.0

Any help or direction is highly appreciated.

**db.serverStatus output**

```
{
    "host" : "c658c885eb90",
    "version" : "3.6.14",
    "process" : "mongod",
    "pid" : NumberLong(1),
    "uptime" : 98,
    "uptimeMillis" : NumberLong(97909),
    "uptimeEstimate" : NumberLong(97),
    "localTime" : ISODate("2019-11-03T16:09:14.289Z"),
    "asserts" : {
        "regular" : 0,
        "warning" : 0,
        "msg" : 0,
        "user" : 0,
        "rollovers" : 0
    },
    "connections" : {
        "current" : 6,
        "available" : 838854,
        "totalCreated" : 11
    },
    "extra_info" : {
        "note" : "fields vary by platform",
        "page_faults" : 0
    },
    "globalLock" : {
        "totalTime" : NumberLong(97908000),
        "currentQueue" : {
            "total" : 2,
            "readers" : 2,
            "writers" : 0
        },
        "activeClients" : {
            "total" : 13,
            "readers" : 0,
            "writers" : 1
        }
    },
    "locks" : {
        "Global" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(14528),
                "w" : NumberLong(12477),
                "W" : NumberLong(5)
            }
        },
        "Database" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(1020),
                "w" : NumberLong(14459),
                "R" : NumberLong(3),
                "W" : NumberLong(6599)
            },
            "acquireWaitCount" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(2)
            },
            "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                "r" : NumberLong(76077321)
            }
        },
        "Collection" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "R" : NumberLong(1018),
                "W" : NumberLong(8805)
            }
        },
        "Metadata" : {
            "acquireCount" : {
                "W" : NumberLong(37)
            }
        }
    },
    "logicalSessionRecordCache" : {
        "activeSessionsCount" : 3,
        "sessionsCollectionJobCount" : 1,
        "lastSessionsCollectionJobDurationMillis" : 0,
        "lastSessionsCollectionJobTimestamp" : ISODate("2019-11-03T16:07:36.407Z"),
        "lastSessionsCollectionJobEntriesRefreshed" : 0,
        "lastSessionsCollectionJobEntriesEnded" : 0,
        "lastSessionsCollectionJobCursorsClosed" : 0,
        "transactionReaperJobCount" : 0,
        "lastTransactionReaperJobDurationMillis" : 0,
        "lastTransactionReaperJobTimestamp" : ISODate("2019-11-03T16:07:36.407Z"),
        "lastTransactionReaperJobEntriesCleanedUp" : 0
    },
    "network" : {
        "bytesIn" : NumberLong(1682811),
        "bytesOut" : NumberLong(1019834),
        "physicalBytesIn" : NumberLong(1682811),
        "physicalBytesOut" : NumberLong(1019834),
        "numRequests" : NumberLong(7822),
        "compression" : {
            "snappy" : {
                "compressor" : {
                    "bytesIn" : NumberLong(0),
                    "bytesOut" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "decompressor" : {
                    "bytesIn" : NumberLong(0),
                    "bytesOut" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        },
        "serviceExecutorTaskStats" : {
            "executor" : "passthrough",
            "threadsRunning" : 6
        }
    },
    "opLatencies" : {
        "reads" : {
            "latency" : NumberLong(61374),
            "ops" : NumberLong(963)
        },
        "writes" : {
            "latency" : NumberLong(13074),
            "ops" : NumberLong(286)
        },
        "commands" : {
            "latency" : NumberLong(988232),
            "ops" : NumberLong(6570)
        }
    },
    "opReadConcernCounters" : {
        "available" : NumberLong(0),
        "linearizable" : NumberLong(0),
        "local" : NumberLong(0),
        "majority" : NumberLong(0),
        "none" : NumberLong(944)
    },
    "opcounters" : {
        "insert" : 246,
        "query" : 944,
        "update" : 40,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 0,
        "command" : 6595
    },
    "opcountersRepl" : {
        "insert" : 0,
        "query" : 0,
        "update" : 0,
        "delete" : 0,
        "getmore" : 0,
        "command" : 0
    },
    "storageEngine" : {
        "name" : "ephemeralForTest",
        "supportsCommittedReads" : false,
        "readOnly" : false,
        "persistent" : false
    },
    "tcmalloc" : {
        "generic" : {
            "current_allocated_bytes" : 8203504,
            "heap_size" : 12496896
        },
        "tcmalloc" : {
            "pageheap_free_bytes" : 2760704,
            "pageheap_unmapped_bytes" : 0,
            "max_total_thread_cache_bytes" : 516947968,
            "current_total_thread_cache_bytes" : 1007120,
            "total_free_bytes" : 1532688,
            "central_cache_free_bytes" : 231040,
            "transfer_cache_free_bytes" : 294528,
            "thread_cache_free_bytes" : 1007120,
            "aggressive_memory_decommit" : 0,
            "pageheap_committed_bytes" : 12496896,
            "pageheap_scavenge_count" : 0,
            "pageheap_commit_count" : 9,
            "pageheap_total_commit_bytes" : 12496896,
            "pageheap_decommit_count" : 0,
            "pageheap_total_decommit_bytes" : 0,
            "pageheap_reserve_count" : 9,
            "pageheap_total_reserve_bytes" : 12496896,
            "spinlock_total_delay_ns" : 0,
            "formattedString" : "------------------------------------------------\nMALLOC:        8204080 (    7.8 MiB) Bytes in use by application\nMALLOC: +      2760704 (    2.6 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist\nMALLOC: +       231040 (    0.2 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist\nMALLOC: +       294528 (    0.3 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist\nMALLOC: +      1006544 (    1.0 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists\nMALLOC: +      1204480 (    1.1 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata\nMALLOC:   ------------\nMALLOC: =     13701376 (   13.1 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)\nMALLOC: +            0 (    0.0 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)\nMALLOC:   ------------\nMALLOC: =     13701376 (   13.1 MiB) Virtual address space used\nMALLOC:\nMALLOC:            415              Spans in use\nMALLOC:             18              Thread heaps in use\nMALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size\n------------------------------------------------\nCall ReleaseFreeMemory() to release freelist memory to the OS (via madvise()).\nBytes released to the OS take up virtual address space but no physical memory.\n"
        }
    },
    "transactions" : {
        "retriedCommandsCount" : NumberLong(0),
        "retriedStatementsCount" : NumberLong(0),
        "transactionsCollectionWriteCount" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "transportSecurity" : {
        "1.0" : NumberLong(0),
        "1.1" : NumberLong(0),
        "1.2" : NumberLong(0),
        "1.3" : NumberLong(0),
        "unknown" : NumberLong(0)
    },
    "mem" : {
        "bits" : 64,
        "resident" : 41,
        "virtual" : 836,
        "supported" : true,
        "mapped" : 0
    },
    "metrics" : {
        "commands" : {
            "buildInfo" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(2)
            },
            "count" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(21)
            },
            "createIndexes" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(5656)
            },
            "drop" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(784)
            },
            "dropIndexes" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(87),
                "total" : NumberLong(87)
            },
            "find" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(944)
            },
            "getLog" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "insert" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(246)
            },
            "isMaster" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(38)
            },
            "listCollections" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "listIndexes" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(1),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "replSetGetStatus" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(1),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            },
            "serverStatus" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(2)
            },
            "update" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(40)
            },
            "whatsmyuri" : {
                "failed" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(1)
            }
        },
        "cursor" : {
            "timedOut" : NumberLong(0),
            "open" : {
                "noTimeout" : NumberLong(0),
                "pinned" : NumberLong(0),
                "total" : NumberLong(0)
            }
        },
        "document" : {
            "deleted" : NumberLong(0),
            "inserted" : NumberLong(246),
            "returned" : NumberLong(398),
            "updated" : NumberLong(40)
        },
        "getLastError" : {
            "wtime" : {
                "num" : 0,
                "totalMillis" : 0
            },
            "wtimeouts" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "operation" : {
            "scanAndOrder" : NumberLong(0),
            "writeConflicts" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "query" : {
            "updateOneOpStyleBroadcastWithExactIDCount" : NumberLong(0),
            "upsertReplacementCannotTargetByQueryCount" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "queryExecutor" : {
            "scanned" : NumberLong(435),
            "scannedObjects" : NumberLong(438)
        },
        "record" : {
            "moves" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "repl" : {
            "executor" : {
                "pool" : {
                    "inProgressCount" : 0
                },
                "queues" : {
                    "networkInProgress" : 0,
                    "sleepers" : 0
                },
                "unsignaledEvents" : 0,
                "shuttingDown" : false,
                "networkInterface" : "\nNetworkInterfaceASIO Operations' Diagnostic:\nOperation:    Count:   \nConnecting    0        \nIn Progress   0        \nSucceeded     0        \nCanceled      0        \nFailed        0        \nTimed Out     0        \n\n"
            },
            "apply" : {
                "attemptsToBecomeSecondary" : NumberLong(0),
                "batchSize" : NumberLong(0),
                "batches" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                },
                "ops" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "buffer" : {
                "count" : NumberLong(0),
                "maxSizeBytes" : NumberLong(0),
                "sizeBytes" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "initialSync" : {
                "completed" : NumberLong(0),
                "failedAttempts" : NumberLong(0),
                "failures" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "network" : {
                "bytes" : NumberLong(0),
                "getmores" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                },
                "ops" : NumberLong(0),
                "readersCreated" : NumberLong(0)
            },
            "preload" : {
                "docs" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                },
                "indexes" : {
                    "num" : 0,
                    "totalMillis" : 0
                }
            }
        },
        "storage" : {
            "freelist" : {
                "search" : {
                    "bucketExhausted" : NumberLong(0),
                    "requests" : NumberLong(0),
                    "scanned" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        },
        "ttl" : {
            "deletedDocuments" : NumberLong(0),
            "passes" : NumberLong(1)
        }
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: can it be related to one of the tests? have you checked if running one single test works?

Comment: try running `db.currentOp()` when it's hanging, it'll show you the query that has the write lock so you can see what's blocking the read operations.

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez yes, if I run a single test it runs just fine. There are no issues.

Comment: @Plancke tried that, it's almost always a different query and on different collections.

Comment: it may be that it is a concrete test which makes it fail. Try to figure out which test or set of test cause it. In other words, from one test to all test, when does it start failing?

Comment: There might be so many reasons why it happens - anything. you can give more information starting from: single instance/shareded, server machine setup (discs, ram, cpus, os), anything else is running on the machines, collection sizes, number of indexes, index/collection data ration, etc.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Nope, somehow it worked for us by updating the docker compose version. I don't think that is what solved the issue but I don't know what did.